# Flash AEC echo cancel

Tags: flash, rtmp, aec

Does anyone know of an online demo of the new flash AEC feature ?
I've seen plenty of demos for RTMFP using webcam, but none that shows of
AEC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here.

http://jfvisuals.blogspot.in/2011/06/acoustic-echo-cancelation-working.html